# Check if a particular element in the array starts with a string

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array `a`:

```
['___', 'abc', 'def']
```

How can I check if `a[0]` starts with `"___"`? I have something like this:

```
a[0].start_with?("___")
```

but I get an error.

Comment: I tried it, works great for me.

Comment: Please post a code example, this should work.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: can you please post the trace/errors you got

Comment: "...an array `a` with values such as `['___', 'abc', 'def']`". is grammatically incorrect. What you mean is you have an an array `a` equal to `['___', 'abc', 'def']`. This may seem picky, but you need to get in the habit of being as precise with your words as with your code. (I see that bugged @sawa as well, who fixed it with an edit.) When you say you want to determine if `a[0]` starts with `"___"`, presumably the answer is "yes" if `a[0] = "___Sal, is that you?"`. Correct? Note you can write `a[0]` as `a.first`.

Comment: This works for me too. Do you plan to use use the a[0] value?

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
a = ['___', 'abc', 'def']

a[0].start_with?("___")
#=> true
```

You can try this if you are getting errors with above code

```
a[0] =~ /^___/
#=> 0
```

this will return you the position it matched your regex in your case it should be `0` (as you are matching it to start of string)

or `nil` if it doesnt match. 
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E

Answer (score 0):

```
a[0].start_with?("___")`
```

This line is correct except you seem to have a backquote at the end